# Javascript's .value and jquery's .val() functions return wrong value...but only on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, mobile-devices

I'm tearing my hair out over this issue.  I have javascript code that looks like this:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
function readVals(){
  val1 = $('#select1').val()
  val2 = $('#select2').val()
  val3 = etc.
}
</script>

<select id='select1'>
 <option value='val1'>val1</option>
 <option value='val2'>val2</option>
</select>
<select id='select2'>
 <option...
```

The readVals method works just fine when running from a desktop, tested on Firefox, Chrome, Safari and from Mac, Ubuntu and Windows.  However, from Android and iPhone, regardless of mobile browser, $('#select2').val() always returns 0.  What's more bizarre is that I constructed another test function like this:

```
function getVal2(){
  alert($('#select2').val())
}
```

`getVal2()` is declared right before `readVals()`, in the `<head>` of the page and it alerts the correct value, even on mobile devices.  So I run `getVal2()` and see the right value.  Then I run `readVals()` immediately after and get the wrong value, but only for `val2`, and only on mobile devices, but on any mobile browser.

Any ideas?

Comment: oh, and I should note: tried exchanging $('#select2').val() with document.getElementbyId('select2').value and got the same results.

Comment: the `option` attribute is `value` not `val`.

Comment: oh I was writing this from memory, whoops.  My code uses 'value', not 'val', so that's not the issue.  I'll fix it in the question.

Comment: That's the problem, you were writing from the memory. Could you please post exact html and js in answer or create jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG, I just realized what the issue was.  As soon as added `var` to make it local:

```
var val2 = ...
```

then the problem went away, but it just occurred to me why the issue was only on mobile devices: I simplified and shortened my code to ask the question, but the actual name of the variable was `orientation`, which I'm guessing is used by mobile devices to describe how the device has been rotated.  That explains why the values coming in from mobile devices were 0 and 90 (as in degrees).  Stupid stupid stupid.  Well that only took three days to figure out.  Sorry for wasting your time.  Next time I will post the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try calling your function only after the page is rendered, using pageinit event?

```
$(document).live( 'pageinit',function(event){
    readVals()
});
```